# more than one javascript tag in the same web page

Tags: javascript

I'm using two separate JavaScript files and including them on the same page using two separate script tags. One of these files works fine and it's the one related for a date picker and the other one that has functions in it doesn't.

BUT! If I take the contents of the second js file that has functions inside and drop them in the wep page it works fine... Kindly help me through this..

Here are some parts of the code:

```
<head>
<?php include('header.php'); ?>?>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Student Details</title>
```

this is where I included the first js file and it working fine (date picker)

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="../js/datetimepicker.js"></script>
```

this is where I included the second file and it has js functions

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="../js/myFuntions.js"></script>
```

this is a js functions that calls functions for the js file (there is no error in the functions that I'm using)

```
<script type="text/javascript">

// here I placed a function that called other js functions for the js file that i included but is not working

</script>

</head>
```

so when took these js functions and placed them in another file and included it on the web page, the stopped working!

Comment: Woozy... I'm... Woozy...

Comment: Perhaps you could show the `<script>` tags that don't work? (Also, have you never heard of the [logical and `&&` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_AND_%28.26.26%29)?)

Comment: <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="../js/myFuntions.js"></script>

this is the one that is not working... and i tried to clean up the code a bit in order to be more clear

Comment: Define "doesn't work". Are you sure the file gets loaded / exists?

Comment: First thing is to open up Webkit Inspector and go to the Network tab (or whatever the Firebug equivalent is). Make sure the JS file even loads.

Comment: what i did is that i took the JS fuctions and placed them myFunctions.js file and inluded them using the <script> tag. when i didn't they stopped working and the page stopped doing any validation.

Comment: You're not by some chance setting something like `window.onload` in both scripts, are you?  Everything that need to run in real time is being called from the functions in your third SCRIPT tag, right?

Comment: yes that is right, i didn't use any window.onload anywhere. and yeah in the SCRIPT tag i created a function that calls functions in the JS file but it's not working

Comment: I think you'll need to give us more information than "they stopped working".  Have you proven to yourself that they are actually loading (using Firebug or Chromes Web Developer tools or some such?)  Have you set break-points in the code you expect to call those external files?

Comment: they are working for sure because i used to have these JS functions on the same web page but then i decided to put them on a separate JS file and include it in the web page. when i did that it stopped working

Comment: So it sounds more like "they aren't working for sure".  Have you done any of the things I or darkporter suggested?

Comment: my browser kept on crashing and crashing I don't know what happened to it! I un-installed and then installed it again and things are working just fine! :) thnx guys and excuse me for what happened coz me myself I tried everything and it didn't work. the browser was the problem. thnx again..
I'm gonna delete my question soon coz it seems useless for other users here... do you think?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you don't need the `language` and `type` attributes.  You can get rid of them since they just make things harder to read.

```
<script src="../js/myFuntions.js"></script>
```

Now you can see that in your question *and* the comment you posted you misspelled "Functions" so try fixing that.

```
<script src="../js/myFunctions.js"></script>
```

Comment: If valid HTML matters (and it seems to be a good idea), it's worth noting that the language attribute for script elements was deprecated in HTML 4 and removed in HTML 5. The type attribute is required in HTML 4, but has a default value in HTML 5 of "text/javascript". Not all browsers in use are HTML 5 compliant, so it seems reasonable to include the type attribute for some time yet.

Comment: @RobG Since HTML5 has not yet been standardized, I don't think any browsers in use are "HTML5 compliant".  Design decisions in HTML5 (like the abbreviated DOCTYPE and optional `type` attribute) were made with backwards compatibility in mind.  Crockford, who has done a fair amount of JS research, says that [this has not been necessary since Netscape 2](http://javascript.crockford.com/script.html).

Comment: @Dennis—hence why documents should try to be as HTML 4.01 compliant as possible. Yes, type is virtually irrelevant and has been for some time, but validators complain if missing in HTML documents < #5. Crockford's comments are interesting given the nit–picking of JSLint. I guess a linter isn't a validator. :-)